# Please undelete mistakenly deleted answer

Tags: support, status-completed

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52138269/how-to-cause-unable-to-flush-stdout-broken-pipe-in-perl) I answered was flagged as a duplicate of [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50507849/weird-error-after-perl-upgrade-unable-to-flush-stdout/52139990), so I copied my answer over.

In an effort to clean up the duplicate, the moderator deleted the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52139990/589924) to the still-open question instead of deleting the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52139965/589924) to the closed question (which I promptly deleted myself).

This was surely a mistake as the comment the moderator left me said I should have answered the still-opened question ("Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates"<sup>[1]</sup>).

So now I'm left without either answer. I flagged the issue for moderation 6 hours ago to no avail.

---

1. Ironically, it's following these instructions that lead to my answer being deleted!

Comment: Just a tip: If one of the posts is deleted, it is highlighted in the mod queue as deleted and we'll leave the remaining one alone (unless there are other issues like NAA or multiple dupes). If either is still active, the default mod action will be to handle the dupe(s) as the dupes are auto flagged instead of the original post.

Comment: @Samuel Liew, I'm not sure if you mean "newer duplicate answer" or "answer to the duplicate question" as "dupes", and this ambiguity leads to opposite readings. I suspect you mean the former, and that you're saying 1) the mistake was probably made because the default action was taken, and 2) had I deleted the original, none of this would have happened. If so, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Yes, I meant newer duplicate answer(s), if there is valid reason for them to be kept over the previous one, please do either of the following: 1. Edit the newer post so that it's no longer the same, or 2. Self-delete the older one (preferably before re-posting). This will provide a better signal to mods on which ones should be kept.

Comment: From the post timelines, I can see that both answers were still active (not deleted) when a mod handled the newer answer.

Comment: Correct. It didn't occur to me there'd  be a reason to delete an answer to a closed question. But you have shown otherwise

Comment: Just providing more clarity on the auto flag to keep in mind. Nobody is really at fault here as it's a minor misunderstanding and mods do get hundreds of auto flagged duplicated posts every day.

Comment: Yup. Like I said, thanks for the tip